# Sur « le moins du monde » vs. « pas le moins du monde »

Tags: expressions-idiomatiques

> Voyons, décide-toi! tu as tort, si tu sens *le moins du monde* que cela
>   te fait du bien.

(*Madame Bovary*, deuxième partie, vers la fin du [Chapitre XVI](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/48359/48359-h/48359-h.htm#ch24))

Je sais que l'expression soutenue *pas le moins du monde* signifie *pas du tout*.

Et je sais aussi que *le moins du monde* signifie, au moins selon [cette source](http://www.cnrtl.fr/lexicographie/moins), *un tant soit peu*, qui donc selon [cette source](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/french-english/un-tant-soit-peu) signifie en anglais *a little bit* ou même *(even) remotely*.

Ma première question sera si l'expression *un tant soit peu* est aussi soutenue que *le moins du monde*.

Et ma seconde question sera si *si tu sens le moins du monde que cela te fait du bien* peut être donc traduite en anglais comme ça : "if you feel even remotely that that is good for you."

Si mes sources sont correctes, et je n'ai aucune raison de m'en douter, alors ma traduction sera correcte.

Comment: Es-tu certain(e) d'avoir voulu écrire *je n'ai aucune raison de m'en douter* (I have no reason to suspect it) ? Et pas *je n'ai aucune raison d'en douter* (I have no reason to doubt them) ?

Comment: @Laure Oui, absolument sûr. _... de m'en douter..._, _... to suspect it [their being correct]..._. Why?

Comment: Je pense alors que *je n'ai aucun moyen de le savoir* serait plus clair. Mais bon c'est peut-être moi ... *moyen* plutôt que *raison*.

Comment: If you’re reading “Tu as tort” to mean “You’re wrong **for not staying over** [if you think there's the slightest chance that it might do you some good]” then I think your translation is fine, but if you see “Tu as tort” as meaning “You’re wrong **for feeling even remotely that it would be good for you**” then I think it would alter the intent of Charles’ words. ?Could the omission of “pas” in “[pas] le moins du monde” be similar to the careless but prevalent omission in Eng. of “n’t” in “could[n’t] care less”(=“pas du tout”)=“You’re wrong for thinking that it wouldn’t do you any good at all”?

Answer (score 2):

Je dirais que *le moins du monde* est plus soutenu que *un tant soit peu*.

Pour ma part, je pourrais utiliser *un tant soit peu* à l'oral, alors que je n'utiliserais pas *le moins du monde*. Par contre, je pourrais utiliser sa forme négative *pas le moins du monde* qui est plus courante.

Je ne connaissais pas *remotely* mais d'après ce que j'ai vu, ça semble tout-à-fait correspondre. L'idée est "even if just a little bit".

Comment: Sans aucune autre source que mon ressenti, je dirais que "le moins du monde" est moins soutenu que "un tant soit peu" mais aussi moins usité. Pour moi, c'est son caractère désuet qui lui donne l'air soutenu (c'est un peu ce qui ressort de ta 2ème phrase. "Le moins du monde" n'est pas du tout une expression courante, quel que soit son niveau de langue, contrairement à la forme négative qui est tout à fait courante.)